# Query to tick rows values against colums

Tags: sql, oracle

For a web page content I want to write PL SQL Query. In this web page have columns of products such as CAR,BIKE,VAN,LORRY,JEEP etc. In the same page have rows of customers.

Once the customer have a CAR, It should be ticked. Same customer can have multiple products. Therefore he can be ticked more products against his name.

How to write a query for this?

View:

```
        cars   bike    van   jeep   lorry  cab   bus   

john    *                     *                   *

smith          *

shane                                       *     *    

mark                   *      *       *     *     *
```

Comment: It sounds like you need an [Outer join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) of "customers" to "products".  If not null, then you display a "tick", otherwise leave it blank.

Comment: Provide some sample data for your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

A query might be created like

```
select c.name as "name", 
       max(case when s.product_id = 1 then '*' end) as "cars",
       max(case when s.product_id = 2 then '*' end) as "bike",
       max(case when s.product_id = 3 then '*' end) as "van",
       max(case when s.product_id = 4 then '*' end) as "jeep",       
       max(case when s.product_id = 5 then '*' end) as "lorry",       
       max(case when s.product_id = 6 then '*' end) as "cab",       
       max(case when s.product_id = 7 then '*' end) as "bus"       
  from sells s
  left join customers c on c.id = s.customer_id  
 group by c.id, c.name 
 order by c.id
```

with the <kbd>[illustration](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=95769fb98058d97a0cf5668e6745068f)</kbd>